# Is it possible to get the timestamp associated with a given history ID?

Tags: gmail-api

I've read through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list) for the list method associated with the history resource, but I wanted to ask to confirm: is there any way to retrieve the timestamp associated with a given historyId?

An example use case: I read an email, and then I archive it, resulting in two historyIds with two labelsRemoved[] lists, listing UNREAD and INBOX labels as removed. It would be very useful to know whether the delta between those events was 3 seconds (indicating that I may have realized the email was useless, archiving it immediately), or 3 minutes (indicating I likely read the email in full).

If this isn't possible, is there a workaround y'all would suggest? Or is adding the timestamp to a history response something you'd consider adding in the future?

Comment: As you say, there doesn't seem to be a timestamp associated to a historyID. There is a creation date on the [message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages) though, so maybe you can compare the date when you receive the history change and the message creation to now how long it's been since you received it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such property yet in the Gmail API as of now.

Comment: Appreciate the response but I'm trying to get the timestamp associated with a history resource (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history), not a message. internalDate doesn't appear to be a property of a historyId.